# Nav Bar won't stay put in Bootstrap site

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

I am unable to get the navbar on this website to stay fixed to the top. I have no idea where I am going wrong. Can you tell me what the trouble is?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45419155/website/index3.html

Comment: The reason is because instead of using the first div as row, change that to the nav. It's working correctly the way you have wrote the code, check out the example on the website and look how they do it [link](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)

Comment: I did that, and I don't see any change whatsoever. It still floats down the screen as I scroll. Could you be more detailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked you are using wrong Bootstrap's class to make fixed nav bar.

**Your code:**

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <ul class="sf-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Services</a> </li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> </li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a> </li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Instead of using `navbar-static-top` please use `navbar-fixed-top` this will solve your problem.

**Problem solved:**

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <ul class="sf-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Services</a> </li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> </li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a> </li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I have tried to make change with your website and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar is made up of an un-ordered list (`ul`) of list-items (`li`).  Your navbar is "fixed" to the top because your `ul` has the class "sf-menu" which looks like this:

```
.sf-menu {
    position: fixed;
}
```

If you would like the navbar to remain in-place relative to the rest of the elements, I recommend that you change or over-write the class "sf-menu" to read `position: relative`.  This will change the appearance of the navbar, but you can manipulate that by removing / overwriting the class "navbar-default" in your `nav` element.

Comment: YES! Thank you so very much.